# setoid_rewrite with impl doesn't work with lemmas of type `A -> B`

Tags: coq, ltac

Example:

```
Require Import Basics.
Require Export Setoid.
Require Export Relation_Definitions.
Set Implicit Arguments.

Lemma simple1 (A B : Prop) (f : A -> B) (x : A) : B.
Proof.
  assert (f2: impl A B) by exact f.
  setoid_rewrite <- f2.
  exact x.
Qed.

Lemma simple2 (A B : Prop) (f : A -> B) (x : A) : B.
Proof.
  setoid_rewrite <- f.
  exact x.
Qed.
```

`simple1` works, but `simple2` fails with

```
Ltac call to "setoid_rewrite (orient) (glob_constr_with_bindings)" failed.
Ltac call to "setoid_rewrite (orient) (glob_constr_with_bindings)" failed.
Cannot find a relation to rewrite.
```

I'd like to use `rewrite_strat`/`Hint Rewrite`'s discrimination tree to write my own proof search, using the `impl` relation to simulate `apply`. But `setoid_rewrite` only works with `impl` if I restate lemmas using `impl` instead of `->`, which is annoying. Is there any way to get `setoid_rewrite` to accept lemmas of type `A -> B` and use the `impl` relation?

Comment: A possible workaround is to replace all the usual logical implications in the context with the ones based on `impl`, e.g. `repeat match goal with
  | f : ?A -> ?B, A : Prop, B : Prop |- _ =>
      (change (A -> B) with (impl A B) in f)
  end.`

Comment: Oh, and I forgot to mention that you would need to modify the script above to adopt it to nested arrows like `A -> B -> C`, etc.